# bash displays print on the same line

Tags: bash

I have a bash script that calls a function to get a package directory.
I'm trying to debug the called function(_ros_package_find) and added some echo statements.

```
pkgdir=`_ros_package_find $1`
echo 'debug rosbash first $pkgdir', $pkgdir


function _ros_package_find {
    echo 'debug rospackage find', $1
    local loc
    loc=`export ROS_CACHE_TIMEOUT=-1.0 && rospack find $1 2> /dev/null`
    echo 'loc', $?
    if [[ $? != 0 ]]; then
        return 1
    fi
    echo $loc
    return 0
}
```

Now, the final display looks like this -

```
debug rosbash first $pkgdir, debug rospackage find, roscpp_tutorials loc, 0 /opt/ros/lunar/share/roscpp_tutorials
```

Not sure, why the 'debug rospackage find' is displayed within echo statement of the final echo statement and not within its own line.

Comment: Notice the output of the following commands: `echo 'I am $USER', $USER` and `echo "I am $USER", $USER` ; The easy solution is to have two `echo` commands, one for each line, if that is what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script might benefit from some modifications (see below updated version of the script).

Q: why the 'debug rospackage find' is displayed within echo statement of the final echo statement and not within its own line.

A: The output of the following line:

```
echo 'debug rosbash first $pkgdir', $pkgdir
```

Will be:

The text "debug rosbash first $pkgdir" followed by the result of the command in `$pkgdir` which is the command `_ros_package_find`

In the below example you can see that the `tempvar` variable holds the result of running the `ls` command, when running `echo "debug debug", $tempvar` - you will get one line of result:

```
$ ls
123  234  345
$ tempvar=$(ls)
$ echo "debug debug", $tempvar
debug debug, 123 234 345
```

When running two `echo commands` e.g. below - you'll get two lines of output:

```
$ echo "debug debug"; echo $tempvar
debug debug
123 234 345
```

---

Modified version of your script:

```
#!/bin/bash
pkgdir=$(_ros_package_find "$1")
echo "debug rosbash first $pkgdir", "$pkgdir"

function _ros_package_find {
    echo 'debug rospackage find', "$1"
    local loc
    loc=$(export ROS_CACHE_TIMEOUT=-1.0 && rospack find "$1" 2> /dev/null)
    echo 'loc', $?
    if [[ $? != 0 ]]; then
        return 1
    fi
    echo "$loc"
    return 0
}
```